# Regex, removing recurring characters but keeping at least one

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm using this

```
html = html.replace(/([^0-9]).*?\1/ , "");
```

but it's not quite doing what I'm trying to do. I want to replace the doubles within a string, but still keep at least one of them. Can't seem to figure out how to go about this.

Comment: `"biig badd maan".replace(/([^0-9])\1+/g , "$1");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THink you mean this,

```
str.replace(/(.)\1+/g, '$1')
```

or

```
str.replace(/([^0-9])\1+/g, '$1')
```

Comment: You may use dotall modifier there. When using dotall  modifier  dollar should match very end of the string.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I have double checked, and I see no problem with my approach. I am sure that `/s` won't do anything since `.` is not present in the pattern. Please [check again](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39055628/3832970).