# Regex to remove certain number of \n at the end of string

Tags: php, regex

How to remove maximum number of `\n` at the end of string using regex?

The `\n` removal is as expected when search position at start of the string `^`, but i can't have a correct result when search position at end of the string.

```
$subject = "\n\n\nsubject\n\n\n";
# maximum removal
$count = 2;

# expect maximum 2 LF removed, 2 removed
var_dump(preg_replace("#^\\n{0,$count}#",null,$subject));

# expect maximum 2 LF removed, 3 removed
var_dump(preg_replace("#\\n{0,$count}\$#",null,$subject));
```

however when using \r both script result as expected

Comment: @rock321987 result still same

Comment: You can use `preg_replace("#\n{1,$count}\\z#","",$subject);` to remove 1 to `$count` newlines at the end of the string. See http://ideone.com/jVa6N2

Comment: Use this universal one `(?:\r?\n){1,N}$` works every time. For this you don't need the `\z` anchor, it's equivalent to the trim whitespace `\s+$` Or, use `^(?:\r?\n){1,N}|(?:\r?\n){1,N}$` for both.

Comment: So, in the strict sense you should only match once because `preg_replace()` infinite wisdom decided to default to _global_ (what engine does that anyway?). You only need to do this when using a _range_ quantifier instead of an open ended one (`+`). By matching _once_ your problem is solved. `preg_replace("#\\n{0,$count}$#",null,$subject,1)`

Comment: This `preg_replace("#\\n{0,$count}$#",null,$subject,1)` will only yield correct results in the current scenario because it will remove the first 2 `\n`s before the final `\n`, while the task is to find and remove `\n`s **at the end of the string**. If one wants to use a similar approach to replace with some text, the results will be not as expected just because the result will be `TEXT<replacement><LF>` and not `TEXT<LF><replacement>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex to remove some specific number of newlines at the end of string, you need to use `\z` anchor that matches at the very end of the string:

```
$subject = "\n\n\nsubject\n\n\n";
$count = 2;
echo preg_replace("#\n{1,$count}\\z#",null,$subject);
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/jVa6N2)

The `$` anchor may match at the final newline in the string, thus, you cannot use it. Also, there is no point matching 0 newlines to remove them, thus, `1` should be the lower bound for the limiting quantifier.

However, you may make `$` match at the very end of the string by using `/D` modifier (*PCRE_DOLLAR_ENDONLY modifier*):

```
preg_replace("#\n{1,$count}$#D",null,$subject)
                           ^^^
```

Here is some relevant excerpt from the [PHP PCRE documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php):

> A dollar character (`$`) is an assertion which is *TRUE* only if the current matching point is at the end of the subject string, ***or immediately before a newline character that is the last character in the string (by default)***.
>   ...
>   *The meaning of dollar can be changed* so that it matches *only at the very end of the string*, by setting the `PCRE_DOLLAR_ENDONLY` option at compile or matching time.

**ANSWER TO COMMENTS**:

The problem OP has is **to remove a specific amount of newline symbols only (NOT `\r\n`, nor mixed `\r` or `\r\n`) at the end of the string**. Note, not after the last non-newline char, but at the end of the string. Let's now test the current solutions (see [the demo code](http://ideone.com/oINi0d)). Note the code below does not remove the newlines, it replaces with a literal `\n` sequence to see what was actually replaced.

```
$subject = "subject\n\n\n";
$count = 2;
echo preg_replace("#\\n{0,$count}\$#","\\n",$subject); // OP - "subject\n\n\n"
echo '"'.preg_replace("#\n{1,$count}\\z#","\\n",$subject).'"'; // mine removes 2 at the end:
//"subject
//\n"
echo '"'.preg_replace("#(?:\r?\n){1,$count}$#","\\n",$subject).'"';//sln's - "subject\n\n"
```

So, here we need to remove 2 (or 1 if there are not 2) newline symbols at the end of the string that has 3 newline chars. That means, the expected result is `"subject\n"`.

- OP current regex: 3 replacements are performed, which means, all newlines are removed
- My solution: 1 replacement at the very end of the string (thus, the result is `"subject\n`"  - **what OP needs**.
- sln's regex from comments: 2 replacements are peformed, that would yield the same results as OP solution.

Let's compare how OP and my regexes work with `preg_replace` against `"\n\n\nsubject\n\n\n"` string:

- `\n{0,2}$` - the first 2 `\n`s are found, but `$` cannot assert the end of string, and further backtracking does not find the end of string position -> the next position is checked. Then the same things happens (again 2 `\n`s not before the end of string). Then there is one `\n` and `s` -> another fail as `s` is not the end of string. Then the `s` is tested This repeats until the regex engine reaches the `\n` after `t`: two `\n`s are matched, and the `$` asserts the position at the end of the string but before the final newline. *Match*, and the replacement takes place. Then, the string is not parsed fully yet, the regex engine processes the string, and matches the single newline that remains, and `$` asserts the position at the very end of the string now -> anothe match and replace happens. And since the regex only asserted the position at the end of the string, but has not consumed it, and the regex `\n{0,2}$` can match an empty string, there is a 3rd match and replace operation.
- `\n{1,2}\z` - (MINE) - The first 2 `\n`s are found but the very end of string position was not, fail. Then the same situation repeats. Then `\ns` is checked and `\n` passes the test (since `\n{1,2}` can match one `\n`), but then there is no the very end of string. This way the engine reaches the `\n` after `t`. 2 `\n`s are matched, but there is no *very end of the string* before the final newline, thus **we have a fail here**. The next match is a success, because there are 2 `\n`s and there is nothing after them.

Comment: The explanation is correct, if the downvoter thinks that `$` always matches at the end of the string, there are at fault. I am adding an alternative solution with the `D` modifier.

Comment: working as expected, and upvoted for downvote compensation :)

Comment: Great I could be of help. Some people are too quick to downvote without evening taking a look at the demo, nor at the regex documentation.

Comment: Since `\n{1,N}` is greedy, it will consume all of the newlines at the end of the string then match the EOS anchor `$` because it can match before or after butt is controlled by the expression preceeding it.

Comment: Sure thing buddy. Using this regex `(\n{1,2})$([\S\s]?\z)` you can see the match  `$\z` https://regex101.com/r/aB7cW2/2 and the match `$\n\z` https://regex101.com/r/aB7cW2/1 when both have $1 the same length. Both are controlled by the preceding expression relative to the string. If you have any questions, feel free to ask. The fact that the second one matches a `\n` between `$` and `\z` is _utterly irrelavent!!_

Comment: Fwiw: The `$\n\z` will only matter if replacement is _required_ at the very end of string where there is actual text to replace, as opposed to blank. That's why universally `\s+$` is used to trim, not `\s+\z`.

Comment: @sln: You forget that `preg_replace` replaces all matches the regex matches, so `/g` should be enabled, see https://regex101.com/r/vX5tG8/1. The result of `(\n{1,2})$([\S\s]?\z)` is not what OP expects. `\s+$` is out of question, OP **needs to repace a *certain* amount of newlines at the *end of the string***. I added a demonstration of the current OP regex, mine and your `"#(?:\r?\n){1,$count}$#"` solutions. It is clear my solution is correct and working.

Comment: @sln: I disagree with *The fact that the second one matches a `\n` between `$` and `\z` is utterly irrelavent!!*, because it is only irrelevant when you need to remove *all* newlines at the end of the string and either use `+` or a limiting quantifier with `max` bigger than the number of trailing newlines. Otherwise, **`preg_replace` may be "fooled" when the `min` param is `1` and it finds a match before the final newline in the string**. Just like the scenario OP encountered. Since the first match was found before the final newline, and the regex could match 1 more `\n`, it had to replace it.

Comment: The fact that _preg_replace_ defaults to _global_ is unfortunate when it comes to matching a _limited range_ of whitespace at the end given anchor `$` For that I'd recommend `echo '"'.preg_replace("#(?:\r?\n){1,$count}$#","",$subject, 1).'"';`

Comment: @sln: That is a good idea. However, that also means my answer is correct.

Comment: I would say your answer is a fix to disallow global modifier, more than a correct interpretation of EOS anchor `$`. The real answer has nothing to do with `\z`, it's matching once. And my answer is _more correct_ in the strict sense.

Comment: @sln - which is your answer? `'"'.preg_replace("#(?:\r?\n){1,$count}$#","",$subject, 1).'"'`? It returns an expected result in this case only because the matches are removed. If they were to be replaced with something else it would not be correct because that code would replace not at the end of string -> `"subject\n<LF>"`. See http://ideone.com/u9JSEq. My solution is a *solution* and not a workaround.

Comment: Sounds like you're repeating what I've already said, anytime a range is used (as opposed to an open ended quantifier), and a _non-blank_ replacement is used and you need it to be last, even a non-global replacement should use `\z`. This is the _only_ time a `\z` should actually _ever_ be used, otherwise you don't really know what `^$` and all their little helpful stuff does. Using open ended quantifiers never requires `\z`.

Comment: @sln: So, as you have just found out, it is not the *only* time, we should always use `\z` when we need to match some text *only* at the very end of the string, and `$` when we do not care if there can be a trailing newline after it or not.

Comment: Are you putting words in my mouth? That's not what I said. I said, concerning newline, using a range and a substitution of non-blank text is the _only_ time `\z` should be used, global or not. This `\n+$` leaves no newlines at the end even when substituted once, and is perfectly fine to substitute `"text\n\n\n\n"` becomes `"text<subtext>"`.

Comment: What I am driving at is that the `\z` and *count* argument solutions are working equally well here, and that your downvote is not valid since the answer is correct.

Comment: According to my POV, `\z` and `$` are having different meaning in this context which is explained well by Wiktor here..

Comment: I like the solution as well as the discussion with examples. Additionally, pointing out the difference between `$` and `\z` makes the answer even more valuable.

Answer (score -1):

Keeping things Simple is an art and never will it be a Science. Simplicity is light (as opposed to heavy & weighty)... it also defies logic since it has NOTHING more to show than just itself: Simplicity ;-) The Code below follows the Line of Simplicity... and it just as well does it too...however; not the geeky way... only the simple way that both you (and the machines as well) understand...

```
<?php

    $subject    = "\n\n\nsubject\n\n\n";
    $count      = 2;

    # EXPECTS 2 LF REMOVED AND SURE ENOUGH: ONLY 2 REMOVED...
    var_dump(preg_replace("#^\n{" . $count . "}#",null,$subject));

    # EXPECTS 2 LF REMOVED AND AGAIN, INDEED: ONLY 2 REMOVED...
    var_dump(preg_replace("#\n{" . $count . "}\$#",null,$subject));
```

Comment: my bad for ambiguous desc, i edited to include maximum in desc