# Removing specific repeated special characters in a row, but keep at least one in each occurrence with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new-ish to JS and regular expressions confuse me a lot so I'm struggling and have been googling for a hot minute.
I found a similar question here [Regex, removing recurring characters but keeping at least one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009113/regex-removing-recurring-characters-but-keeping-at-least-one) but still cannot figure this out with doing specific special characters. (/*-+.)

I'm building a calculator in javascript and trying to prevent input from looking like this if an operator button gets pressed multiple times:

> 6 *** 6 /// 5 ** 3...2 --- 1 ++ 9

and turn it into

> 6 * 6 / 5 * 3.2 - 1 + 9

instead but still allowing repeats of the operators or decimal in different places. So removing repeated characters happening multiple times in a row. 
 I've tried checking if the last character of the input is a repeat of the value of the operator button you press but that feels clunky. 
I think a regex might be the best way to do this? Correct me if I'm wrong pls. Thank you!

Comment: Capture the next `event` value and if it's == prevent it.

Comment: Just put those characters in a character class: `([./*+-])\1+` https://regex101.com/r/AydEzb/1 Note that `-` needs to be either the first or last character in the class or escaped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex, removing recurring characters but keeping at least one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009113/regex-removing-recurring-characters-but-keeping-at-least-one)

Answer (score 0):

Nick's comment helped! I thought I tried his solution earlier when troubleshooting but turns out I messed up the formatting before and he cleared it up! Thanks! One day I'll understand regexs. (^:

```
let regex = /([./*+-])\1+/;
text.textContent = text.Content.replace(regex, '$1');
```

Comment: If it helped. Please let the answerer i.e. @Nick to answer your question and consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark below his provided answer.

Comment: @Mandy8055 I'm sorry! How do I do that? Since he made a comment and didn't submit an answer, I'm not sure how to choose his comment as the right answer. ): Or do I wait to see if he submits an answer? I'm super new so not sure how things work.

Comment: Please do read [what to do someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). No need apologize. Everyone is there to help and get help. Since you're new to SO; so no matter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `replacing` you can prevent the event.

```
document.getElementById("in").addEventListener("keypress", (evt) => {
  const value = evt.target.value;
  (value.indexOf("*") > -1 ||
    value.indexOf("+") > -1 ||
    value.indexOf("-") > -1) &&
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```